# React: onMouseOut not updating state of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, onmouseover, onmouseout

I'm having problems with updating a state which controls whether or not to display a child component. When I mouse over the ul below it works as expected, but upon leaving the ul element it doens't seem to update state, or atleast it doesn't change the display of child component as I want i to.

I have this chunk of code:

```
<ul
            className="dropDownBtn"
            onMouseOver={this.showDropDownItems}
            onMouseOut={this.hideDropDownhide}
          >
            Supplements
            {this.state.showStatus ? (
              <HeaderDropDown
                firstChem="Alpha Lipoic Acid"
                secondChem="Melatonin"
                thirdChem="Omega 3"
              />
            ) : null}
          </ul>
```

Inside of a component which has these functions & declarations for manipulating state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showStatus: false
    };

    this.showDropDownItems = this.showDropDownItems.bind(this);
    this.hideDropDownItems = this.hideDropDownItems.bind(this);
  }

  showDropDownItems() {
    this.setState({
      showStatus: true
    });
  }

  hideDropDownItems() {
    this.setState({
      showStatus: false
    });
  }
```

Could this have to do with re-rendering of parent component or something else? Thanks.

Comment: Function name mismatch `this.hideDropDownhide` between `hideDropDownItems`

Comment: `onMouseOver={this.showDropDownItems()}`